# Problemas em dar post em api com AXIOS

Tags: node.js, react, api, axios

Preciso que o campo value seja um numero, mas ele só está aceitando String

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
class PostForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

     

        this.state = {
            idCategoria: '',
            description: '',
            date: '',
            value: //aqui preciso que seja um float
        }
    }

    changeHandler = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state)
        axios
            .post('http://localhost:3200/api/v1/lancamento', this.state)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { idCategoria, description, date, value } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="idCategoria"
                            value={idCategoria}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="description"
                            value={description}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="date"
                            value={date}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                    </div>
                            <div>
                        <input
                            type="number"
                            name="value"
                            value={value}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                    </div>
                    
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Inicialize o state como `undefined` e no momento de realizar o envio, converta para float.

```
this.state = {
  idCategoria: '',
  description: '',
  date: '',
  value: undefined
}

const data = {
  ...state,
  value: parseFloat(state.value),
}

axios.post('http://localhost:3200/api/v1/lancamento', data)
```